# Can't get correct peer ip address when accepting TCP socket connection on localhost in Python

Tags: python, sockets, unix, tcp

I am working on a P2P network application code for file transmission. Each peer has a listening socket on which it can accept incoming connections.

**"Server" part of code:**

```
listening_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listening_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

try:
    listening_socket.bind((self.address, self.listening_port))
    break
except SocketError:
    return

listening_socket.listen(5)
listening_socket.setblocking(0)
self.listening_socket = listening_socket

####

new_connection, address = self.listening_socket.accept()
new_connection.setblocking(0)
print 'Accepted new connection from %s' % (peer_address)
```

**"Client" part of code:**

```
try:
    sock = socket.create_connection((peer_address, peer_port), timeout=5)
except socket.error:
    return False
print 'Connected to %s' % (peer_address)

sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.setblocking(0)
```

If I bind the first peer (server) to '127.0.0.1' and the second one (client) to '127.0.0.2' (or any other address from loopback subnet) and connect to '127.0.0.1', **accept()** returns address as '127.0.0.1', instead of '127.0.0.2'. How can I display the correct incoming ip address when accepting the connection?

**getpeername()** also returns '127.0.0.1'.

On local wifi network, it displays the correct incoming ip address.
I mention that the connection itself works well, I just need to display the correct address and not '127.0.0.1'.

Testing on an Unix machine.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: While you claim that you bind the client  to some local address nothing in your code actually does this binding - you only do a connect. If you really bind the client *socket* then please show the code you are using for this. Note that it does not help if you bind an unrelated socket in the client - you have to bind the socket which does the connection (which is not the listener socket).

Comment: By binding the client to '127.0.0.2' I meant binding its listening socket for its server part. AFAIK, a client in a traditional server-client TCP connection needs only to connect to a server to its bound listening socket, in my case '127.0.0.'1 on first peer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless a TCP client is explicitly bound to a local IP address it might use any of the local IP addresses on the interface which provides a route to the target IP. Usually systems have an implicit internal order and the first IP address is used if multiple are available.

In your case you only connect to the target IP 127.0.0.2. This IP address is reachable from both 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2 with the same costs. 127.0.0.1 is likely the first IP address on the loopback interface so this is used as the source IP. If you want to have it different you need to explicitly bind the connecting socket. It does not matter what happens on your listening socket - binding is per socket and not per application.

Binding a client socket is similar to binding a server socket:

```
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('127.0.0.2',0))
s.connect(('127.0.0.2', peer_port))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved my problem. I did not know that you can bind a socket before connecting. But I have one more question. Why does it show the correct IP address if I use the local wifi network, without binding? Does the router bind it internally?